# MVC 3 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I upload a file in my MVC 3 project.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string path = "C:\\";
        string filePath = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
               filePath = path + file.FileName;

                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                file.InputStream.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();

               // other operations, where can occur an exception 
               // (because the uploaded file can have a bad content etc.)
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (file.InputStream != null)
                file.InputStream.Dispose();

            GC.Collect();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); //here is the error
            }
        }
 }
```

in that code, if an exception occured after I saved the file I can't delete it (also I cann't upload it again) because I get the error

> The process cannot access the file
>   '[filePath]' because it is being used by another process.

What's wrong with that code ?

### edit

I had to change the `file.InputStream.Dispose();` to

```
file.InputStream.Close(); 
file.InputStream.Dispose(); 
file.InputStream = null;
```

And, now it's working fine.

Comment: There is no variable named `path`, yet `filePath = path + file.FileName;`, is it set somewhere else?

Comment: I've edited my question, check it now

Comment: Do those "other operations, where can occur an exception" access the file in any way?

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer, and choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the `file.InputStream` is not null inside the `catch` block, you should dispose it inside the `finally` block, like this:

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    try
    {
        filePath = path + file.FileName;

        file.SaveAs(filePath);

        // other operations, where can occur an exception 
        // (because the uploaded file can have a bad content etc.)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); //here is the error
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        file.InputStream.Close(); 
        file.InputStream.Dispose(); 
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

By the way, the `InputStream` property is a read-only property. You can't set it to null.